# Any android stick/TV device with open source code

Tags: android

We want to use Android TV sticks for showing something similar to advertisements (cannot disclose the exact usecase).
Android sticks such as these:
http://www.laptopmag.com/android-sticks.aspx

Here are the requirements from such a device:
- Ability to connect to an external display (via HDMI)
- Ability to connect a mouse to this device (via USB/USB-to-miniUSB converter)

Since we need the both above we cannot use phones like Nexus 5 for running our usecase, rather have to resort to an Android TV stick (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Additionally, **we require the Android Source code for such a device** for enabling some of our usecases. These Chinese Android sticks do not share their Android source code.

Are there any devices which meets all of my requirements above.

Comment: its not **requirements**  site if you have problem with code than show your code SO will help you

Comment: I am basically asking which device can meet my requirements. I thought the coding community would be a good place to ask.. Is there any alternate place I could put this question?